# CSS 2D cube effect

Tags: css

I'm trying to build this:

[image: 2D cube]

I want to make it with just CSS and it needs to be responsive. I'm willing to use an image pattern.

The shadows (the left one and the striped one) can be of different colors. The approach must have that in mind.

This is what I have so far: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/azeos/dqqmvsmp/)

```css
body {
    padding: 50px;
    background-color: #000 !important;
}
.cube {
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    background-color: #000;
}
.cube::before {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 25%;
    left: -28px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 35%;
    background-color: #fff;
    transform: rotate(-70deg) skew(-70deg);
    z-index: 0;
}
.cube::after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: -18px;
    left: -15px;
    height: 40px;
    background: repeating-linear-gradient(-70deg, #000, #000 5px, #fff 4px, #fff 8px);
    z-index: -1;
}
#cube1 {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
}
#cube2 {
    width: 25%;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="cube" id="cube1">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</div>
<div class="cube" id="cube2">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc quis nunc ut justo vehicula iaculis. Duis nec sapien eu nulla congue rhoncus non at mi. Fusce tincidunt accumsan enim quis pharetra. Nunc lorem magna, eleifend sed risus at, molestie auctor nulla..</p>
</div>
```

I can't find a way to get the proper height for the left shadow.

References: [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/stripes-css/), [CSS Shapes](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/)

Comment: Aw, come on, who's the joker trying to close this as "too broad".

Comment: @MrLister boring people. I thought it will fun to solve this. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the left shadow, use only `skewY` instead of `skew` and `rotate`. Then you can position it much more precisely, using `height:100%`.

Now the stripes of the bottom shadow extend to the left of the left shadow... I don't know if you want a wider left shadow or a higher bottom shadow, so I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

```css
body {
    padding: 50px;
    background-color: #000 !important;
}
.cube {
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    background-color: #000;
}
.cube::before {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top:8px;
    left:-10px;
    width: 9px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #FFF;
    transform: skewY(-70deg);
    z-index: 0;
}
.cube::after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: -18px;
    left: -15px;
    height: 40px;
    background: repeating-linear-gradient(-70deg, #000, #000 5px, #fff 4px, #fff 8px);
    z-index: -1;
}
#cube1 {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
}
#cube2 {
    width: 25%;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="cube" id="cube1">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</div>
<div class="cube" id="cube2">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc quis nunc ut justo vehicula iaculis. Duis nec sapien eu nulla congue rhoncus non at mi. Fusce tincidunt accumsan enim quis pharetra. Nunc lorem magna, eleifend sed risus at, molestie auctor nulla..</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome! Didn't know about `skewY`, I have 0 experience with `transform`. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

How about that?

```css
body {
    padding: 50px;
    background-color: #000 !important;
}
.cube {
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    background-color: #000;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
.cube::before {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;    
    left: -11px;
    width: 10px;
    top: 12px;
    height: calc(100% + 4px);
    background-color: #fff;
    transform:  skewY(-70deg);
    z-index: 0;
}
.cube::after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    right: -2px;
    bottom: -30px;
    left: -6px;
    height: 28px;
    background: repeating-linear-gradient(-90deg, #000, #000 5px, #fff 4px, #fff 8px);
    transform:  skewX(-20deg);
    z-index: -1;
}
#cube1 {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
}
#cube2 {
    width: 25%;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="cube" id="cube1">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</div>
<div class="cube" id="cube2">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc quis nunc ut justo vehicula iaculis. Duis nec sapien eu nulla congue rhoncus non at mi. Fusce tincidunt accumsan enim quis pharetra. Nunc lorem magna, eleifend sed risus at, molestie auctor nulla..</p>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/n9qpus7e/

Comment: Thanks for your approach. I like the `calc`, will have it in mind. I marked the @MrLister answer because of the explanation. Your's works just fine. Thanks again.